# How to Install OpenERP plug-in for Eclipse IDE?

Tags: odoo

I recently got informed that there is an OpenERP plugin for Eclipse IDE. Can anybody guide me on how to install it?

I already have an OpenERP server installed. My OpenERP + PostgreSQL + Gedit (with OpenERP snippets) development environment is already set up.

Now, I would just like to try eclipse to see if its better for me to use it instead of Gedit. I have successfully installed Pydev plugin. My problem is, I cant seem to find the OpenERP snippets/plugin.

Thank you

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=openerp+eclipse

Comment: Hi Michael, I already tried that google search. Im just a little confused

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download openerp eclipse template for xml and python snippest from here http://code.google.com/p/openerp-eclipse-template/.

You also find video for how to installe it in same link.

Comment: That repository has not been updated since 2010, so it likely does not work... or does it?

Comment: yes it's not updated , but it does work perfect.

Comment: kool to know; I assumed that maybe it would not work since OpenERP has at least one major release since

Comment: The snippets are working. Thanks man