# Run/debug Openerp7.0 in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS + Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, debugging, ubuntu-12.04, odoo

I'm hesitating on whether to ask this question here or on Ubuntu dedicated site. But I think here will have more probability of being answered. If someone believe it should be moved, please recommend doing it.

After a couple of days struggling with several tutorials and answers as [this one](http://www.theopensourcerer.com/2012/12/how-to-install-openerp-7-0-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts/), [this](http://www.ursainfosystems.com/1/category/openerp%207/1.html), [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186299/eclipse-juno-need-root-access-everytime-i-change-the-configuration/195372#195372), [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13704113/1297603) and more. I finally have *Ubuntu 12.04 LTS*, *OpenERP 7.0* and *Eclipse Juno + PyDev + xml templates* all up, tested and running.

**But** I can't manage to add a new workspace with openerp source folder and therefore I'm unable to debug OpenERP too. I'm newbie working in Linux so maybe some of the steps I've followed I thought was correct but it wasn't. At the end I have the following situation:

- OpenERP is running on a folder located on: */opt/openerp*, and I ran `sudo chmod -R 777 openerp/*`
- Eclipse is running on: */home/eclipse/bin/* and executed `sudo chown -R myuser:myuser eclipse`

I'm creating a new workspace by pointing to my OpenERP folder (see first bullet-point). But once it is added and refreshed it does not show the folders inside, *addons*, *server* and *web*. Here is a screen capture:

[image]

So, I cannot debug also. Opening this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=RTg8VvyEVak#t=10s) will show exactly the step that I can not replicate. When I click on Browse to add a project on a new debug configuration nothing is shown. I guess it has something to do with the workspace not working.

Any clue on what I'm doing wrong? Some other place I can look for answers? Or should I forget about this set and start clean again?

There are several similar questions to this one and I have read'em all, some of them are closed, hope mine will not follow same path.

- [how can I debug OpenERP code in to the eclipse [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12298811/1297603)
- [Python & OpenERP development environment setup howto?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9066774/1297603)
- [How to Install OpenERP plug-in for Eclipse IDE? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13986014/1297603)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grrr!! As usual, asked the question and found where the problem was some minutes later...and it was a really dumb problem, friday makes me idiot... and if someone is struggling with the same issue, my answer is (repeat one thousand times):

> **do not forget to uncheck the "Use default" check box when creating the project**

I was able to browse to the needed folder and create the project on my workspace at once. Now is up, running and I'm able to debug without any issue.

[image: Don't forget to uncheck the use default chekbox]